# Matplotlib returns empty plot when plotting accuracy to learning rate using Keras

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to plot the overall accuracy of my model versus the learning rate in order to compare different sets of optimizers (SGD, Adam, Adagrad, etc). However, when I plot my variables, the outcome of the matplotlib graph is empty

This is for Keras used on Google Colab

## This is my model

```
model = Sequential()
dim = 28
nclasses = 10

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(dim,dim,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', activation='relu',))

model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5,5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(120, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(84, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(nclasses, activation='softmax'))
```

## Selecting my optimizer

```
opt = SGD(lr=0.001)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', factor=0.9, patience=25, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(x=x_train, 
                    y=y_train, 
                    batch_size=10, 
                    epochs=1, 
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[reduce_lr],
                    validation_data=(x_val,y_val), 
                    shuffle=True)
```

## This is the part where I try to plot my model

```
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['lr'])
plt.title('Plot of overall accuracy to larning rate for SGD optimizer')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('learning rate')
plt.legend(['x_train', 'x_test'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph is empty because you have trained for only one epoch. But this is not the worst of your problems. You're trying to plot epoch learning rate (which is constant value) vs epoch validation accuracy. How do you expect it to look if the value of learning rate is constant?

What you should do is to take the value of learning rate that you use for a some simulation and plot it versus the highest value of accuracy you were able to achieve during particular simulation. For example, you train 3 times using different learning rates and then you plot max values of accuracies vs learning rate like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
lrs = [history1.history['lr'][0],
       history2.history['lr'][0],
       history3.history['lr'][0]]
vals = [max(history1.history['val_acc']),
        max(history2.history['val_acc']),
        max(history3.history['val_acc'])]

lrs, vals = zip(*sorted(zip(lrs, vals)))
lrs, vals = list(lrs), list(vals)

plt.plot(lrs, vals)
plt.title('Plot of overall accuracy to larning rate for SGD optimizer')
plt.ylabel('Max Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Learning Rate')
plt.show()
```

Which will result in something like this:

[image]

Here's example of how you should define these simulations:

```py
opt1 = SGD(lr=0.001)
opt2 = SGD(lr=0.01)
opt3 = SGD(lr=0.1)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', factor=0.9, patience=25, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1)
model2 = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model) # <--copy model
model3 = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)

model.compile(optimizer=opt1, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history1 = model.fit(x=x_train, 
                     y=y_train, 
                     batch_size=10, 
                     epochs=10, 
                     verbose=1,
                     callbacks=[reduce_lr],
                     validation_data=(x_val,y_val), 
                     shuffle=True)
model2.compile(optimizer=opt2, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history2 = model2.fit(x=x_train, 
                      y=y_train, 
                      batch_size=10, 
                      epochs=10, 
                      verbose=1,
                      callbacks=[reduce_lr],
                      validation_data=(x_val,y_val), 
                      shuffle=True)
model3.compile(optimizer=opt3, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history3 = model3.fit(x=x_train, 
                      y=y_train, 
                      batch_size=10, 
                      epochs=10, 
                      verbose=1,
                      callbacks=[reduce_lr],
                      validation_data=(x_val,y_val), 
                      shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated! Thank you!